# xml update value using dom in java

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom, updates

I have to change the value that I find in the `eElement` that matches with the old value with another one.

I try with `eElement.setAttribute(...)` function and with `setTextContent` function but it doesn't work.

If we suppose that the new value is stored in a String variable called `newValue`, how can I make my code run?

```
NodeList leaf = doc.getElementsByTagName(relativeLeaf);
System.out.println(leaf.item(0).getNodeName());
for (int temp = 0; temp < leaf.getLength(); temp++) {
    Node nNode = leaf.item(temp);
    if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
        String oldValueInCells = eElement.getElementsByTagName(relativeLeaf).item(0).getTextContent();
        System.out.println("old tag : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName(relativeLeaf).item(0).getTextContent());
        if(oldValueInCells.contentEquals(oldVal)){
            // ####
            // here i have to change tha value in eElement
            // where it match with the old Value with a new one    
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basing on the documentation I think you can get the Node Element and then set a value. You first should get the node element like this:

```
 Node node = eElement.getElementsByTagName(relativeLeaf).item(0); //You get the node here so you can use it as well to create OldValueInCells
 String oldValueInCells = node.getTextContent();
        System.out.println("old tag : " + oldValueInCells);
        if(oldValueInCells.contentEquals(oldVal)){
            // ####
            // here i have to change tha value in eElement
            // where it match with the old Value with a new one    
           node.setTextContent("new value"); //Here you will set the value to the node
        }
```

Source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html

Comment: thanks for your answer =) I try but the method dont update the value. I paste the test code.
     if(eElement.getElementsByTagName("description").item(0).getTextContent().contentEquals("x")){
      
      nNode.setNodeValue("co");
      System.out.println("description : " + ((Element) nNode).getElementsByTagName("description").item(0).getTextContent());
     }

The equals function work well but it don't understand that have to change the value. What can be the problem?

Comment: ((Element) nNode).getElementsByTagName("description").item(0).getTextCo‌​ntent());

I cast the node to element and I apply the function get by tag name

Comment: Hello Valentina, I made a little program using the method "setTextContent("new value")" and is working, can you try to use my code and change the setNodeValue to setTextContent ?

Comment: I based my program on this post: https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-modify-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/ I commented everything between Node staff and TransformerFactory, if you just put between those "staff.setTextContent("test");" you will see that everything in the staff tag will change for "test"